# Entity Framework 4 Stored procedure Should I use Complex Type

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 tables

Customer
Order

2 Classes

Customer
Id-Name

Order Id-Description. CustomerName

My stored procedure returns all orders with the customerName as well.
I have used the normal mapping to a Entities =OrderTable

However my customerName is not populated even though the sp returns it.

Should I use a complex type when you have an sp like

```
     Select or.Id,or.Description,c.CustomerName
     from order or
     join Customer c on c.CustID=or.CustId
     where or.OrderId=1
```

The above is just an example to explain my question.

Not sure but looks like I should use complex no?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Orders` entity does not have CustomerName, it won't be returned unless you create a complex type that includes all resulting columns from the stored procedure.  Another option would be to use a projection or an anonymous type in a simple Linq query, which might work just as well for a query that is this simple.